# VS Code - how to turn off auto start up

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I change in setting to not automatically start my VS Code after restarting my machine?

I've tried searching in settings but could not find this setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be connected with your operating system, not the application itself. Try googling "*insert-your-operating-system-here* startup applications".

Answer (score 0):

go to VSCODE settings:

> Window: Restore Windows

Controls how windows are being reopened after starting for the first time. This setting has no effect when the application is already running.

> select: none